One motor getting hot
I have built an FPV drone, and during the first test flight, one motor failed before even taking off. I replaced that motor, but now the new motor is getting much hotter than the others when I attempt to take off.
I've configured the flight controller using Betaflight Configurator. The replaced motor is spinning faster than the other motors for the same input level (as observed in the betaflight Motors tab). However, the current consumption seems to be the same when each motor is turned on individually for 20 seconds.
Here are the components I'm using: Flight Controller: JHEMCU F4 Nox V3
ESC: ReadyToSky 4-in-1 ESC
Motors: ReadyToSky 7500KV Brushless Micro Motor
Battery: 600mAh 3S Battery
The total weight of the drone is 213 grams.also the accelerometer is correctly caliberated. Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this issue, and how I can troubleshoot it? Thank you!

Have you tweaked the PID controller gains in the Betaflight configurator? Making the D-gain too high is a common cause of hot motors. You can also try measuring/comparing between motors the resistance between each pair of motor wires and seeing if any of them are abnormally high.

No, i havent made any changes in the pid tab. I have also tried resetting the pid settings. Still that particular motor rotates faster compared to other motors to the same input.

Is this with or without propellers on the motors? Perhaps consider trying swapping the propellers around to see if the anomaly follows the motor or the propeller

This occurs with propellers and also without propellers. Moreover the propeller arrangement and motor direction are set correctly

The next troubleshooting step would be to swap two of the motors between ESC ports and see if the issue follows the motor or the ESC. You could also get the same effect by measuring the phase resistance
